# How to generate custom code in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sequence

I want to create a code for a table in postgresql.
The model could looks like:
event {id, code, name, created_by}
The code will start at E0001 and finish at E9999. The idea is to check at insert, if there's no code generate it, else insert the provided code.
I assume I have to use a trigger, but I don't know how to generate that code with that sequence and check if exists or not.
Help.

Comment: What happens when you insert the 10000th row?

Comment: Lets assume will never insert that, although the code could be E10000. The thing here is to maintain the format with zeros, at least until the 9999th row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved by doing this:

Creating a sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq;
```

and setting the DEFAULT value of code with

```
('E'::text || lpad((nextval('seq'::regclass))::text, 4, '0'::text))
```

Thanks both of you since I used the two answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lpad` function to pad the number with zeroes.

```
select 'E' || lpad (45::text, 5, '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `DEFAULT` clause in your column definition that uses a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq;

ALTER TABLE mytab ALTER code SET DEFAULT 'E' || CAST(nextval('seq') TO text);
```